# How do I make a div that of 100% width has always a 50% relative height to its width in a pure CSS way?

Tags: css

I have a div and I have set its width to `100%`

So the div can resize as its parent element or window resizes.

However, I want the div to have a 50% height, what CSS should I write? (or any other percentage, not just 50%)

It seems that `50%` is definitely the wrong way to go.

I can use JavaScript to do this but is there any pure CSS way?

```css
#out {
  border:1px solid #f00;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="out">
stuff<br>
stuff<br>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean you want `#out height` always = x % of `#out width`?

Comment: Read this: https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/

Comment: There is a CSS proposal to add an `aspect-ratio` property - but it is not yet implemented: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

Answer (score 2):

As any percentages assigned to margin and padding are calculated based on `width`, you can use that to maintain the aspect ratio:

```css
#out {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  padding: 25% 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="out">
  stuff<br> stuff
  <br>
</div>
```

The problem with that, though, is that your content further increases the height. For that to be solved, wrap the content in another container, which you give `position: absolute`:

```css
#out {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  padding: 25% 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="out">
  <div class="inner">
    stuff<br> stuff
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```